# Android String Manipulation crashes activity

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to take a String and filter through it until I hit a comma. I have tried this two separate ways and both times my activity has crashed the entire application.

Method 1:

```
Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
String stringToSearch = gotBasket.getString("Path");
String first = "";
for (int i = 0; i < stringToSearch.length(); i++){
    char[] buffer = new char[1];
    stringToSearch.getChars(i, i+1, buffer, 0);
    if (!buffer.equals(",")){
        first = first + buffer.toString();
    }else{
        i = stringToSearch.length();
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
String stringToSearch = gotBasket.getString("Path");
String first = "";
for (int i = 0; i < stringToSearch.length(); i++){
    if (stringToSearch.charAt(i) != ','){
        first = first + stringToSearch.charAt(i);
    }else{
        i = stringToSearch.length();
    }
}
```

After trying both these methods I once again realized why I dislike developing for Android, the only feedback I get is a NullPointerException which doesn't tell me a thing.

EDIT: The path string was in fact returning null, it was a stupid error on my part due to a general lack of sleep, thank you all for answering my question so quickly.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to do some debugging statements to find out if `.getString("Path")` is returning a null.

Comment: Also, just as a comment, java generally adheres to camel case as a coding standard..

Comment: Do you have an example of the String you are trying to parse? Add some debugging to print out the character to know where you are failing.

Comment: can you please show code for how to pass "Path" to intent ?

Comment: try this `if(StringToSearch == null) {System.out.println("String is NULL"); return;}`

Comment: what you try to do is when "," is occurs you have skip rest of text after this char is it ?

Comment: Yes, after checking the path string was null, it was a stupid mistake on my part. Im tired and need to finish this within the next day or so, lots of stupid mistakes have been had. Thankyou all for your answers, stackoverflow never ceases to amaze me with the speed of answers. As with the camel case comment, yes I do code in camel case but once again it's late and i'm tired.

Comment: Why haven't you used debugger (eclipse etc.) to find the bug before adding it to android environment?

Answer (score 0):

Why is your else statement setting it to the string length, I would recommend using break.

What is the purpose of this code?  It seems like you are trying to find the first comma, and use the string before that, once you find the comma you bail.

If that is the case I would probably just do something like

```
Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
String stringToSearch = gotBasket.getString("Path");
String first;

int lPosition = stringToSearch.indexOf(",");

if ( lPosition  != -1 )
{
    // Do you Concat here
    first = stringToSearch.substr(0, lPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
String stringToSearch = gotBasket.getString("Path")!=null?gotBasket.getString("Path"):"";
String first;
if(stringToSearch.contains(",")){
  first = stringToSearch.split(",")[0];
}else{
  first =stringToSearch;
}
```